# subversion - splitting very large website to sub project

Tags: svn

I have a very large web project that is more than 15GB. I am trying to figure out the best way to add the project in subversion.

Most of the time, when a feature is added, the change takes place only on one folder, i.e. each directory at the root level can be treated as standalone app.
Most of the directories at the root level have only one or two dependency folder like shared folder (that contains common include scripts).

Does makes sense to make each directory at the root level a sub projects? If yes, are there other tools such as externals that might be useful to manage dependency.

Or is it better to just add the whole website as a single project and use partial checkout to checkout the directory that you need to update and dependent directory. Will the partial checkout pose problem during branching / merging ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's in the website that is causing it to be so large? Does it include complied code (like Java) or is it the images, etc.

If it's compiled code, you don't need the website in Subversion, just the source files, and that will trim down the size.

However, if the website is really that big (maybe a lot of images and media files), I suggest you break it up into multiple Subversion repositories just for the sake of convenience. If you use httpd as the Subversion server, you can have multiple repositories under a single Apache instance and a single Apache configuration point. This allows you to treat the separate repositories as if they're one single extremely large repository for such things as permissions, checkouts, etc. Yet, it gives you the convenience to move the various separate repos around onto multiple disks, and speeds up access quite a bit.

I wouldn't work about getting more *commercial* software. Subversion is fairly robust.

Comment: I wonder how the tagging feature would work across the multiple subversion project. If I break the big project into multiple independent project, is there a good way to tag multiple project.

Comment: @user883257 You'd have to tag each repository separately, but they could all have the same tag. You could write a simple shell script to tag all repositories with the same tag, and to checkout all of the tags as a single project.

Answer (score 0):

Either solution will work fine. I suggest the first one, in case someone forgets to check out a subdirectory and gets the whole repo instead. Also in case something goes corrupt somewhere, you want to limit the damage and not hold up the entire codebase. When each folder is a separate repo, just make sure users check out the common repo as well at the same level.

Also for this large a project, you may want to consider a more commercial repository software (perforce, mercurial, etc.)